# C# typecasting custom object with generics in it

Tags: c#, generics

I have the follwoing:

subObject, superObject where subObject is a subclass of superObject.

I can always upcast subObject to superObject, but i cannot do the following:

```
wrapperObject<superObject> instance = (wrapperObject<superObject>) wrraperObject<subObject> instance2;
```

This is an example with generic lists:

```
            List<Object> l1 = null;
            List<Boolean> l2 = null;
            l1 = (Object)l2; <<< This will not work

            Object o1 = null;
            Boolean o2 = false;
            o1 = (Object)o2; <<< This works
```

I understand that in case with lists I can just iterate thru all the objects within the list and typecast them individually.
But this will not work in case of my custom class "wrapperObject"

```
        wrapperObject<superObject> l1;
        wrapperObject<subObject> l2;
        l1 = (wrapperObject<superObject>)l2;  <<< this doesnt work


        superObject a = null;
        subObject n = null;
        a = (superObject)n;  <<< this works
```

Comment: You are referring to the concepts of Covariance and Contravariance (the `in` and `out` keywords). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: Normally I would suggest you monkey patch the method table pointer of the list object and the underlying array, but in this case you can't even do that because Object and Boolean are not the same size!  So what you're asking for is just not sensible.

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume for a moment that this would be possible

```
List<bool> lb = new List<bool>();
List<object> lo = (List<object>)lb;
```

Now, we could do

```
lo.Add(123); // Since lo is typed as List<object>
```

but `lo` is just a reference pointing to `List<Boolean> lb`. Bang!

A workaround for this type of problem is to have a base type (class or interface) that is not generic and derive a generic one from it. For instance, `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>` which implements `IEnumerable`. I.e., this assignment is valid:

```
IEnumerable e = new List<bool>();
```

---

Note that you can do this type of conversion with arrays. I.e., you can assign

```
object[] obj = new Person[10];
```

The price we must pay for this is efficiency, since a type test is performed when we assign an array element. This type test can throw an exception if we assign a non-compatible value. See: Eric Lippert's Blog on [Array Covariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/)

Comment: I'm still confused. Does it me this is impossible to convert it like this? Is there a workaround for it then?

Comment: The assignment compatibility of element types does not translate in assignment compatibility of collection types (or generic types in general).

Answer (score 1):

Oliver's answer is totally right, it explains why you simply can not do this. But I can think of an instructive workaround that besides helping you to achive what you want, it will help you to better understand Covariance and Contravariance in .Net. Consider the following classes:

```
class SuperObject { }

class SubObject : SuperObject { }

class WrapperObject<T>:IContravariantInterface<T>,ICovariantInterface<T> where T : SuperObject
{
    public void DoSomeWork(T obj)
    {
        //todo
    }

    public T GetSomeData()
    {
        //todo
        return default;
    }
}
```

We make Wrapper implementing two interfaces: `IContravariantInterface<T>` and `ICovariantInterface<T>`. Here are they:

```
interface IContravariantInterface<in T> where T : SuperObject
{
    void DoSomeWork(T obj);
}

interface ICovariantInterface<out T> where T : SuperObject
{
    T GetSomeData();
}
```

By doing this we split up Wrapper functionality into two parts: a covariant one and a contravariant. Why doing this? Because by doing this we can safetly cast either from most derive classes to less ones or the other way around with the condition that we are using the right interface:

```
    var superObjectWrapper = new WrapperObject<SuperObject>();
    var subObjectWrapper = new WrapperObject<SubObject>();

    ICovariantInterface<SuperObject> covariantSuperObjWrapper = subObjectWrapper;
    IContravariantInterface<SuperObject> contravariantSuperObjWrapper = subObjectWrapper; //does not compile

    ICovariantInterface<SubObject> covariantSubObjWrapper = superObjectWrapper; //does not compile
    IContravariantInterface<SubObject> contravariantSubObjWrapper = superObjectWrapper;
```

By casting to these interfaces you are sure that you can only access those methods that are safe to use regarding your casting

**EDIT**

Base on OP's comment below consider writing converter logic in your Wrapper class. Take a look to the following refactored WrapperObject:

```
class WrapperObject<T> where T : SuperObject
{
    private T _justATestField;

    public void Copy<TType>(WrapperObject<TType> wrapper) where TType : SuperObject
    {
        if (wrapper._justATestField is T tField)
        {
            _justATestField = tField;
        }
    }

    public WrapperObject<SuperObject> GetBaseWrapper()
    {
        var baseWrapper = new WrapperObject<SuperObject>();
        baseWrapper.Copy(this);
        return baseWrapper;
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
    var subObjectWrapper = new WrapperObject<SubObject>();
    WrapperObject<SuperObject> superObjectWrapper = subObjectWrapper.GetBaseWrapper();
```

Comment: but ICovariantInterface<SuperObject> is not the same as WrapperObject<SuperObject>. And i have an async function that suppose to return Task<WrapperObject<SuperObject>> and will not take anything else. That's the reason i cannot return WrapperObject<SubObject> directly without casting it

Comment: @AnKing see my edits, I think you can write custom logic inside your wrapper to achieve that

Comment: My WrapperObject processes more than just subObject and superObject, in fact it is more than 100 of different objects. This is my REST Api response wrapper, therefore it cannot be narrowed down to superObject, or can it?

Comment: @Anking, what do you mean? But after all those 100 different objects are all derived from your base class, aren't they?

Comment: no, thay are not. There are only 2 particular ones that are related.

Comment: Then in order to not narrow down to superObject you can make `GetBaseWrapper` an extension method, and remove the SuperObject type constraint from `Copy` so that it works with whichever type, you will only need to validate if the given parameter type is assignable from `T` and custom business logic stuff

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about are [Variant Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces). Right now, C# only allows Variant Generics on Interfaces and only in one direction. The two types of generic variance are covariance where the output of a function can be more precise than the declared variant type or contravariance where the input of a function can be less precise than the declared variant type.

If your interface needs to do both on the same variable, you're out of luck.